# Nonzero Riemann Integrable function with zero 2-norm

Tags: real-analysis

I need an example of a nonzero real function $f$ which is Riemann integrable on $[ -\pi,\pi ]$ and $||f||_2=(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^2(x) dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}=0$.

is a piecewise function like $f(x)=0$ when $x \not =\pi $ and $f(x)=1$ when $x=\pi$ considered Riemann integrable on $[-\pi, \pi]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is! All you need to be able to do is find relevant dissections! There are various notations used - probably best to just check your definition, then it should be reasonably straight forward to get this results. Basically, you can just take a dissection $\mathcal D =\{-\pi, \pi - 1/n, \pi\}$. We see that the first term always gives zero, and the second gives $1/n$. As $n \to \infty$, we see that this tends to zero, and hence the integral is zero! :) Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

A discontinuous function can be integrable as long as the set of discontinuities has "measure 0." In particular, a finite set of discontinuities is fine. So you could just set $f(\pi) = 1$ and $f = 0$ everywhere else and work out what the integral of the square would be. Hint: as your Riemann integral partition becomes finer and finer, what happens in the one subinterval that contains $\pi$?